# Is it possible to Refresh a Related List on a Page Layout?

Tags: salesforce

Is it possible to refresh a single related list on a **Standard** Page Layout after a related list button is clicked (possibly using Ajax with OnClick JavaScript)? Has anyone attempted something like this?

I'm aware that this is possible using Visualforce, and I may need to go that route.

Comment: Probably, but it'd be a hack.  A lot easier to just refresh the whole page ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After digging around in the `main.js` JavaScript file included on all standard Salesforce pages, I found a way to get an array of all Related Lists on a Page. This is a "hack", and it is not guaranteed to work (and is certainly not supported, especially after each new release of Salesforce).

```
window.sfdcPage.relatedLists; // returns an array of related lists
```

There are available functions on each of the Related Lists returned. Each list can be refreshed by calling the `makeRLAjaxRequest` function.

```
// where 4 is the Related List number
window.sfdcPage.makeRLAjaxRequest(null,window.sfdcPage.relatedLists[4].listId);
```

Comment: +1 for highlighting that it's a hack, sucks when we have to resort to using these techniques but it's also unavoidable!